# RecyclerView.Adapter onCreateViewHolder is called when notifyItemChanged() called

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have simple adapter which looks exactly like this:
[Adapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058#file-simpleadapter-java-L1)

Except data item is way more compllicated than just a string.

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.TopicContentViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private List<ModelTopic> mData;

    public void add(ModelTopic s,int position) {
        position = position == -1 ? getItemCount()  : position;
        mData.add(position, s);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void updateNightMode(boolean isNightMode) {
        if (mData.size() > 0) {
            mData.get(0).setNightMode(isNightMode);
            notifyItemChanged(0);
        }
    }

    static class TopicContentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.view_pager)
        FixedAspectRatioViewPager viewPager;
        @BindView(R.id.circlePageIndicator)
        CirclePageIndicator circlePageIndicator;

        @BindView(R.id.wv_details_text)
        WebView wvDetailsText;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TopicContentViewHolder vh, final int position) {
        Log.d("SimpleAdapter", "BindViewHolder");
        ModelTopic topic =  mData.get(position);

        final int curTextColor = NightModeFragment.getCurrentTextColor(mContext, topic.isNightMode());
        vh.detailsHeaderText.setTextColor(curTextColor);
```

As you can see, I have a WebView inside element which can be larger than the size of the screen, so one single element doesn't fit inside screen.

I want to change color of some textViews in the  **TopicContentViewHolder** 
so I set color based on data I have. Then, when I want to change color, I change data and call

```
notifyItemChanged(position)
```

But I have unexpected scrolling.
I think it is because my method **onCreateViewHolder** is called when I invoke **notifyItemChanged**

Here is my log output:

```
05-19 17:15:38.620 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: createViewHolder
05-19 17:15:38.640 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: BindViewHolder
//all above called when I enter fragment and adapter is created

05-19 17:15:48.535 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: createViewHolder
05-19 17:15:48.555 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: BindViewHolder
//above called when I change notifyItemChanged() first time

05-19 17:15:50.447 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: BindViewHolder
//above called when I change notifyItemChanged() 2 time

05-19 17:15:52.910 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: BindViewHolder
//above called when I change notifyItemChanged() 3 time

05-19 17:15:53.183 27303-27303 D/SimpleAdapter: BindViewHolder
//above called when I change notifyItemChanged() 4 time
```

As you can see, onCreateViewHolder called twice. First time is obvious, but second time is a mystery to me. 
Any help here?

Comment: It seems like the unexpected scrolling is ultimately the thing you're trying to fix, can you describe more exactly what it is you're seeing so we can understand the issue?

Comment: When I call notifyItemChanged() I see my list scrolls up to the beginning. The next time I call notifyItemChanged() it stays still. 3 time - stays still. Take a look at log output.